# How do I check efficiently if IEnumerable has a single element?

Tags: c#, performance, linq, ienumerable

[`Count()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb338038(v=vs.110).aspx) scans through all element, hence `if (list.Count() == 1)`will not perform well if enumerable contains a lot of elements.

[`Single()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb155325(v=vs.110).aspx) throws exception if there are not exactly one elements. Using `try { list.Single(); } catch(InvalidOperationException e) {}` is clumsy and inefficient.

[`SingleOrDefault()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342451(v=vs.110).aspx) throws exception if there are more than one elements, hence `if (list.SingleOrDefault() == null)` (assuming `TSource` is of reference type) will not work for enumerables of size greater than one.

Comment: `Any()` has at least one  item, `Skip(1).Any()` - has not the second item

Comment: `FirstOrDefault() == default(T)` ?

Comment: @JohnSmith: That won't detect the difference between "one" and "more than one"

Comment: How do you define "best way"? I think your question is *only* opinion-based.

Comment: I agree that it is impossible to choose the best solution that caters to everyone. I am open to get all opinions before deciding on a solution. I do not want take an extreme approach and replace "best way" with "most performant" or "most readable".

Comment: @JatinSanghvi And this is exactly what makes the question opinion-based, as there´s no determinsitc way on defining what "best" means. You don´t provide enough information and thus there´s no "the best". In particular future readers might define best completely different, so answers provided here won´t help them in any way.

Comment: AFAIK (ref source) Count downcasts to ICollection first- wouldn't worry about it enumerating in many cases.

Comment: @HimBromBeere, I have an OData client method that takes in `IEnumerable<HttpRequestMessage>` as its argument. Depending on whether the list contains single or more requests, I will be sending a plain HTTP request or OData batch request to the service. IMO, sharing all these details will make the question less relevant to the visiting users than making a simplified problem statement.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

more direct:

```
public static bool HasSingle<T>(this IEnumerable<T> sequence) {
    if (sequence is ICollection<T> list) return list.Count == 1; // simple case
    using(var iter = sequence.GetEnumerator()) {
        return iter.MoveNext() && !iter.MoveNext();
    }
}
```

Note, however, that you can only guarantee that you can read a sequence once, so *in those cases*: by the simple fact of checking that there *is* a single item, you can no longer get the item. So you might prefer something that gives you the value if there is one:

```
public static bool HasSingle<T>(this IEnumerable<T> sequence, out T value)
{
    if (sequence is IList<T> list)
    {
        if(list.Count == 1)
        {
            value = list[0];
            return true;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        using (var iter = sequence.GetEnumerator())
        {
            if (iter.MoveNext())
            {
                value = iter.Current;
                if (!iter.MoveNext()) return true;
            }
        }
    }

    value = default(T);
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Are there any types that implement `ICollection` where retrieving the `Count` is slow? _I am guessing `ConcurrentDictionary` maybe?_

Comment: @mjwills since it is an interface: *any* random implementation could be arbitrarily slow. But we can *reasonably expect* that it will be fast - or at least, fast enough. I wouldn't class `ConcurrentDictionary<...>` as "slow" for this purpose - checking the count should still be faster / cheaper than creating an enumerator and trying to enumerate it once/twice, then disposing the enumerator.

Comment: My apologies, I thought `ConcurrentDictionary`'s snapshot semantics (including locking) might make it more expensive.

Comment: @mjwills it does have such semantics for Count, and it locks the whole dictionary (for writing, because reading is lock free) and then loops through all buckets to calculate total number of items. So in theory it can be slower than creating enumerator and get first two items (because that is lock free). Not that it matters much in this case of course. And with concurrent collection to which you write from multiple threads operation is question is not very meaningful anyway. Now it has 1 item and millisecond after it already has 100.

Comment: @Evk fair enough :)

Comment: I wonder why someone downvoted this answer, it's the best one out of 7 existing.

Comment: I would suggest one addition: Returning false—or an explicit throw if the logic called for it—when the original sequence is null. So, add `if (sequence is null) return false;` before the `using` in the first version, and `if (sequence is not null)` immediately after `else` in the second.

Answer (score 21):

```
var exactlyOne = sequence.Take(2).Count() == 1;
```

The `Take` extension method will not throw if there is less elements, it will simply return only those available.

Answer (score 7):

To avoid the extra iteration in the other answers, you could implement your own extension:

```
public static bool HasExactlyOneElement<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source)
{
    using (var enumerator = source.GetEnumerator())
        return enumerator.MoveNext() && !enumerator.MoveNext();
}
```

Answer (score 6):

I suggest playing with `Any`, we have to check that

1. `list` has at least one item - `Any`
2. `list` doesn't have the second item - `!list.Skip(1).Any()`

Code:

```
  bool isSingle = list.Any() && !list.Skip(1).Any();
```

However this approach has drawback: It scans `list` *twice* which can be an issue in case of `IQueryable` (the query executes *two* times with potentially different outcomes and additional overhead)

**Edit:** Some sequences are *not repeatable* (e.g. if we read a *file* or query a *database* `list` can *vary* between calls). In such a case we should ensure just *one call*, e.g.

```
  // We ask at most 2 items - Take(2)
  // And check if we have exactly one item
  bool isSingle = list.Take(2).Count() == 1;
```

Comment: Note that not all sequences are repeatable; this will fail if `list`: isn't repeatable

Comment: @MarcGravell could you expand a little bit on why list.Skip(1).Any() might be a problem if  list not repeatable? (what does repeatable mean?)

Comment: @Zigzagas: if `list` gets items from a *file*, *database query* etc. i.e. some *outer source* this source can *change* between `list.Any()` and `list.Skip(1).Any()`. To be on the safer side of the road we must ensure, that we have *exactly one call*, e.g. `list.Take(2).Count() == 1;`. I've edited my 5 years old answer.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `!Skip(1).Any()`:

```
bool contains1 = items.Any() && !items.Skip(1).Any();
```

You could create an extension which is more efficient if the type is a collection:

```
public static bool ContainsCountItems<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, int count)
{
    ICollection<TSource> collectionoft = source as ICollection<TSource>;
    if (collectionoft != null) return collectionoft.Count == count;
    ICollection collection = source as ICollection;
    if (collection != null) return collection.Count == count;
    int itemCount = 0;
    using (IEnumerator<TSource> e = source.GetEnumerator())
    {
        checked
        {
            while (e.MoveNext() && ++itemCount <= count)
            {
                if (itemCount == count)
                    return !e.MoveNext();
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Usage:

```
var items = Enumerable.Range(0, 1);
bool contains1 = items.ContainsCountItems(1); // true;
items = Enumerable.Range(0, 2);
contains1 = items.ContainsCountItems(1); // false;
```

You can use this extension with any type and any count, so not only 1

```
var items = Enumerable.Range(0, 10);
bool contains10 = items.ContainsCountItems(10); // true;
```

Answer (score 2):

Each Linq method call (`.Any()`, `.Skip()`, ...) you call on the original enumerable creates an enumerator, which could also be a considerable performance hit depending on your requirements.

So you could use `.Take(2).Count() == 1`.

See also [There's a most performant way to check that a collection has exactly 1 element?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/253369/theres-a-most-performant-way-to-check-that-a-collection-has-exactly-1-element).

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use Linq for whatever reason, you can also manually work with the [Enumerator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ienumerable.getenumerator%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396):

```
/// <summary>
/// Checks that the IEnumerable&lt;T&gt; has exactly one item
/// </summary>
public static bool HasSingleElement<T>(IEnumerable<T> value)
{
    using ( var enumerator = value.GetEnumerator() )
    {
        // Try to get first element - return false if that doesn't exist
        if ( !enumerator.MoveNext() )
            return false;

        // Try to get second element - return false if it does exist
        if ( enumerator.MoveNext() )
            return false;

        // exactly one element exists
        return true;
    }
}
```